# boolean statement for string contained in Json

Tags: python, json

If I have Json data that looks like this:

```
import json

rawData= {
"Date": "2020-08-16T13:37:22.501743", "MeterReading": 199
}
jsonData = json.dumps(rawData)

print(jsonData)
```

In Python how could I create a boolean statement to know if the Json object contains only string `Date` and `MeterReading`? If I use this...

```
mystring = "MeterReading Date"
for key in jsonData:
    if key in mystring:
        print('yes')

    else:
        print('no')
```

this will print something unwanted as shown below. Ideally if the Json object contains `Date` and a timestampt, as well as `MeterReading` to contains some sort of float or int value. Any tips greatly appreciated...

```
no
no
yes
yes
yes
yes
no
no
yes
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
yes
no
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
no
no
no
yes
no
no
no
no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operate on the dict directly. `json.load` or `json.loads` it if necessary.

Then use the fact that in many ways dict keys behave like sets:

```
>>> rawData.keys() == {'Date', 'MeterReading'}
True
```

Comment: this works thanks. Can I use `rawData.keys()` to create boolean statement if `MeterReading` would be int or float?

Comment: @HenryHub no, you would have to manually check the types of `rawData.values()` for that.

Comment: Any chance you could give me one more tip? If i use `rawData.values()`  this prints `dict_values(['2020-08-16T13:37:22.501743', 199])`. how could i verify with boolean statement this contains a time stamp as well as a float/int value?

Comment: @HenryHub: You're asking essentially a different question. Accept this answer already!

Comment: 2 more minutes :)

Comment: Any chance you could help me with this one greatly appreciated... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431565/python-convert-json-object-to-list-to-verify-contents

Answer (score 0):

String iteration is done character-by-character, not by space-separated word. You need to split `myString` first (or use a list in the first place):

```
mystring = "MeterReading Date"
mywords = mystring.split()
for key in jsonData:
    if key in mywords:
        print('yes')

    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: Would you know how I could turn it into a boolean statement other than printing `yes or no` a dozen times?