# python convert json object to list to verify contents

Tags: python, json

If I have Json data that looks like this:

```
import json

rawData= {
"Date": "2020-08-16T13:37:22.501743", "MeterReading": 199
}
jsonData = json.dumps(rawData)

print(jsonData)
```

How could I verify with a boolean statement `jsonData` contains a legitimate time stamp (that `pandas` would understand) and the `MeterReading` would either be a float or integer value?

Is converting json object to list marching down the correct path?
`l = list(rawData.values())`

I can print these values individually but I think they are still strings...?
`print(l[0], l[1])`

Any tips greatly appreciated..

Comment: How would you normally detect whether `pandas` can understand a time stamp?

Comment: Is your `rawData['Date']` supposed to always be in ISO format?

Comment: I apologize for not knowing @quamrana, the only thing I do when using Pandas is reading csv file. IE, `df = pd.read_csv('./sample_data/data.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)` Is it possible to `try` read into pandas `index_col='Date', parse_dates=True` and `if else exception` occurs `pass`...?

Comment: Can you use `pd.to_datetime(...)` to check dates in `rawData` before they get converted to `json`?

Comment: ok sounds good thanks